# JDBC - MySQL Calling Stored Procedure

Tags: javascript, mysql, stored-procedures, jdbc, callable-statement

I'm using the follwing code to connect to a database:

```
var ServerIP = '[ip]'; 
var SQL_Port = '3306';
var SQL_Usr = '[user]';
var SQL_Pwd = '[pass]';
var SQL_DB = '[db-name]';

var connectorInstance = 'jdbc:mysql://' + ServerIP+':'+SQL_Port;
var ConnectString = connectorInstance+'/'+SQL_DB;

var conn = Jdbc.getConnection(ConnectString, SQL_Usr, SQL_Pwd);
//Executes the queries
var execStmt = conn.createStatement();

var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
doc.setActiveSheet(doc.getSheetByName('Sheet1'));

var mysqlQuery = execStmt.executeQuery("select Name, Status From data_table ORDER BY Name");
var cell = doc.getRange('A2');

var row = 0;
while(mysqlQuery.next()) {
for(var i=0; i<8; i++) { 
cell.offset(row, i).setValue(mysqlQuery.getString(i+1));
}
row++;
}

mysqlQuery.close();
execStmt.close();
conn.close();
```

I need to use the following stored procedure:

`call procedure_name()`

After googling all over, I couldn't understand where and how in the code should I implement this line.

Comment: is that realy java???

Comment: That's what wikipedia says... *"Java Database Connectivity (JDBC) is an application programming interface (API) for the programming language Java"*

Comment: yes but your code looks like java script

Comment: Alright, changed tag to javascript

Comment: Are you running this javascript on the JVM, otherwise you don't have JDBC.

Comment: I'm running this on Google Spreedsheet script editor.

Answer (score 0):

To invoke a procedure You need to use a [`CallableStatement`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/CallableStatement.html)

```
String aString = ...
int aNumber = ...
CallableStatement cs = conn.prepareCall("{call procedure_name(?, ?)}");  
cs.setString(1, aString); 
cs.setInt(2, aNumber);
cs.executeUpdate();
```

note that passing values is similar to a `PreparedStatement`

Comment: replace procedure_name with your procedure name, replace ?, ? with the right number of parameters, if presents set the parameters, then call executeUpdate

Comment: I don't know the number of parameters, this call should simply expose another type of rows in the database, which currently do not get output. And I don't understand in-between where should I paste this snippet, in my current code?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you google `JDBC CallableStatement`.

This [article](http://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/jdbc-callablestatement-stored-procedure-out-parameter-example/) for example has a complete example. In your case, try something like:

```
CallableStatement cstmt = null;
try {
   String SQL = "{call procedure_name()}";
   cstmt = conn.prepareCall (SQL);
   conn.executeUpdate();
}
catch (SQLException e) {
   //
}
finally {
   cstmt.close();
}
```

But note that your code is NOT java, so you will have to rewrite it entirely.

---

EDIT:

Google Script seems to rely on the Java implementation. So it should work the same way.

Try:

```
var conn = Jdbc.getConnection(ConnectString, SQL_Usr, SQL_Pwd);
var callableStmt = conn.prepareCall("call stored_procedure_name()");
callableStmt.execute();
callableStmt.close();
conn.close();
```

Comment: Your code is not java, so you can't put it in your exact code. Also, does your procedure really is `procedure_name` ?

Comment: no, that's just for example. can you provide an answer that allows me to put it in my exact code?

Comment: I just saw it now. I can only use javascript in Google spreadsheet. wouldn't it be possible to convert your shorter piece of code to javascript, rather than convert my whole original code to Java?

Comment: I tried inserting the second variation `TypeError: Cannot call method "prepareCall" of undefined.` first one doesn't work either...

Comment: This error means that your `conn` is null. Where did you put the code ? Did you open the connection first ?

Comment: places it after `var execStmt = conn.createStatement()`, where shall i place it?